# 12.0.1 iPhone 6s Support Files for Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to build an app to test it on my iPhone6s, however the iOS version is 12.0.1, I managed to find 12.1 support files (which are too new) I need to find the 12.0.1 support files / or if someone can tell me how to force the iPhone6s to update to 12.1 ?

I cannot upgrade Xcode because Mac is too old. I've done this before, all I need is the support files for 12.0.1, but I cannot find them.

[image]
[image]

Comment: “how to force the iPhone6s to update to 12.1” But that’s trivial. Just install the 12.1 beta.

Comment: “all I need is the support files for 12.0.1, but I cannot find them” Xcode 10 contains the iOS 12 SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this repo:
[github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport](https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport)